# React.js The select box option does not go into jsx and $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)

Tags: reactjs

I used the method of pushing html into jsx using the arrangement. This is a replacement for `insertAdjacentHTML`. However, the value in the Select Box looks empty. So I printed out the value of the option array with console.log.These values were then obtained. 
`0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "option", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}`
I heard that direct DOM operation in React is not good. So I used the following method. But is this method also wrong?
The response data is not problem.

```
axios.post(url, params)
  .then(function(response) {
    for(let i in response.data.mapList) {
      const code=response.data.mapList[i].CODE;
      option.push(<option value={code}>{code}</option>)
    } 
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })

  return(
    <select>
      {option}
    </select>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with this approach is that you call axios..post on every render of the page.
A simple approach using Functional component would be:

```
const Select = ({options}) => 
<select>
{options.map((option, key) => 
   <option key={key} value={option}>{option}</option>
   )}
   </select>
   
   
const App = props => {
 const [options, setOptions] = useState([])
 useEffect(() => {
   //your axios code
   setTimeout(() => { //just to simulate a server response after 1 second
     setOptions(['option1', 'option2','option3'])
   }, 1000) 
 }, [])
 
 return <div>
  <Select options={options} />
 </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you return the JSX element before the AJAX call end (Axios is a library that makes async call)

So just change your code to this :

```js
// create an async function
// I passed the url and params as function parameters...but you can also use them as you did before 

const retrieveOptions = async (url, params) => {
  // Wait for the response
  const { data } = await axios.post(url, params);
  return (
    <select>
      // Loop over the response to build and return your JSX
      {data.mapList.map(({ CODE }) => (
        <option value={CODE}>{CODE}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```